# Problema con Tailwind en un proyecto nuevo de Laravel 8 con Jestream

Tags: laravel, tailwind, laravel-jetstream

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto nuevo de Laravel 8 con Jetstream y Tailwind.
El problema es que faltan muchas clases en el archivo generado luego de correr el comando npm run dev. El archivo app.css resultante solo tiene 2000 lineas de coddigo y pesa solo 47 kb en lugar de los 4 mb que tendria que pesar.
Cuando quiero utilizar clases como bg-red-500 o text-green-400 no aplica los estilos ya que en el app.css no estan esos estilos. La version de tailwind que se instalo luego de crear el proyecto es la 3.
Alguien sabe porque ocurre esto ya que en otros proyectos del pasado con versiones anteriores de jetstream no tenia problemas.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Ya pude entender cual era el problema. En esta nueva version de tailwind v3 cuando corres npm run dev analiza tus archivos html y solo compila las clases que utilizas. Hay que corren npm run watch para que este observando continuamente los cambios y ahi funciona perfecto. A medida que utilizas las clases de tailwind las va compilando y las agrega al archivo app.css.
Saludos comunidad.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, exactamente ahora iba a plantear esa pregunta pero con tu comentario me corre bien . Gracias